# Ruby on Rail - undefined method `admin?' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, cancancan

I am using `gem 'devise'` and `'cancancan'` for defining roles for user. problem is when I run rails server its says: `undefined method 'admin?' for nil:NilClass`

**ability.rb:**

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    if user.admin?
      can :manage, :all
    else
      can :read, :all
    end
  end
end
```

**User model:**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :projects

  def admin?
    self.admin
  end
end
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: you don't have a current user so this fails you could add a guard clause or implement in the same fashion as the [Abilities Docs](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/defining-abilities)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing the line from where the error is originating is something like:

```
if can? :manage, @object
  # ...
```

This is likely causing an error because your user is not logged in.

The method defining the abilities looks like this:

```
def initialize(user)
  if user.admin?
    can :manage, :all
  else
    can :read, :all
  end
end
```

So, if you have no user, the line `user.admin?` will cause an error because `user` is `nil` and `nil` has no `admin?` method.

I would do something like this:

```
def initialize(user)
  if user.try(:admin?)
    can :manage, :all
  else
    can :read, :all
  end
end
```

`try` in Ruby won't throw an error but will return `nil` if the method doesn't exist.

(I have not tested this and since you're not sharing the error, I'm taking some liberties in the response.)

---

I'd also like to point out that if the `admin` attribute on your `User` model is a boolean, you don't need to define this method—Rails does that automatically for you.

```
def admin?
  self.admin
end
```

Answer (score 0):

**ability**

```
class Ability
 include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    if user.has_role? :admin
     can :manage, :all
    else
     can :read, :all
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This method is used with rolify [link](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify/wiki/Devise---CanCanCan---rolify-Tutorial)

Comment: The OP mentioned nothing about rolify, and the user model he's showing does not have a `has_role?` method.